# Inserir multiplos ids a uma tabela

Tags: mysql

Olá,

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho a tabela PESSOA e tabela CURSO, cada pessoa pode escolher mais de um curso, o id dos cursos escolhidos precisam estar salvos dentro da tabela pessoa, qual seria a melhor forma de se fazer?

Comment: Está referindo-se apenas a parte da modelagem do banco e ao SQL?

Comment: Isso mesmo, eu pensei em gravar dentro de um varchar todos os ids mas acho que é gambiarra

Answer (score 2):

O ideal seria você ter um modelo de tabelas parecido com esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesses casos você se pergunta:

- Uma **Pessoa** pode ter quantos **Cursos**?
- A Resposta é "N" Cursos, uma pessoa pode ter de 0 até N cursos.
- Um **Curso** pode ter quantas **Pessoas**?
- A Resposta também é "N", um curso pode ter de 0 até N pessoas.

Quando nós nos deparamos com essa situação de N-N existe a necessidade de surgir uma tabela auxiliar para ligar as duas tabelas que no caso é a tabela "Pessoa_Curso", ela só existe com o intuito de fazer a ligação de Pessoa com Curso.

Comment: Nesse caso quando eu for inserir um registro ficaria da seguinte forma: 


INSERT INTO Pessoa_Curso VALUES(1,10)
INSERT INTO Pessoa_Curso VALUES(1,12)

Para a pessoa_id = 1 terá o curso 10 e 12

Está correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo, dessa forma dá certinho, depois só recupera com where pessoa_id=1

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certinho aqui